# A Basic Akka Http Routing question: reconciling signatures

Tags: scala, functional-programming, routes, akka-http

The following code exemplifies a common pattern in Akka http routing:

```
lazy val routes:Route {... 
  pathPrefix("aPath")
    path(Remaining) { dirName => 
      get { 
        onComplete(aFuture(dirName)) {
          case Success(res) => handleResult(res)  
          ...
```

My question concerns the final 2 lines of this code.

How is the signature of onComplete() compatible with the return value of handleResult()?

The signature of onComplete() is,
 `def onComplete[T](future: ⇒ Future[T]): Directive1[Try[T]]`  The signature of handleResult() is `def handleResult(result: Either[ChazErrors,OurOwnInfoRecordCaseClass]): StandardRoute`

How is `StandardRoute` compatible with `Directive1[Try[T]]` ? As I understand Akka Http (I am a newbie), Directives produce Routes, but Routes are not equivalent to Directives.

Comment: Akka-Http has implicit conversions that convert results to the necessary types - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068547/how-is-akka-http-marshaling-implemented-under-the-hood describes something similar to the conversion that you require

Comment: Thanks, P J, I will look up that answer. I should have said: my example is made out of working code. The question for me was not whether, but why, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](https://richardimaoka.github.io/blog/akka-http-marshalling-details/) by Richard Imaoka explains all the `implicit` conversions going on.

Specifically w.r.t. the fact that `Route`s are not `Directive`s, this implicit conversion takes care of that:

```
object StandardRoute {

//...

/**
 * Converts the StandardRoute into a directive that never passes the request to its
 * inner route (and always returns its underlying route).
 */
implicit def toDirective[L: Tuple](route: StandardRoute): Directive[L] = 
  Directive[L] { _ ⇒ route }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, László, for this informative answer. Looks spot-on. I will read all of this. --Ben